# Adding transform/animating an element causes tooltip to be overlapped by other elements

Tags: html, css

I have a working layout for an HTML page, but when I attempted to add some animation to it, it caused the tooltips to be overlapped by other elements in the page.

I've created a simple fiddle that replicates the setup I have pretty closely:
https://jsfiddle.net/y5bk4utg/

Removing the following lines:

```
animation: 0.3s ease var(--delay) 1 slideInFromLeft;
transform: translateX(-100%);
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

from .group causes the tooltip to display properly again.

I've googled around and it seems that the issue is that the translate/transform property causes each one of the "group" elements to have it's own stacking context. However, when I attempted to follow the solutions posted in other threads, I could not fix the issue. I'm pretty new to HTML/CSS in general, so it's most likely that I was not implementing the fixes correctly. Could someone please give me some guidance?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a `z-index` issue. You have them all set to the proper z-index on the tooltip div itself, but the container divs need to have the proper values to have them overlap correctly - you don't, so they simply push behind the next parent div.

Since you already have inline styles added, you can add:

```
<div class="group" style="--delay:.2s; z-index:3"></div>
<div class="group" style="--delay:.4s; z-index:2"></div>
<div class="group" style="--delay:.6s; z-index:1"></div>
```

By reducing the values sequentially, you make it possible to overlap the tooltip below the hovered div. This is not dynamic, and if the tooltip changes so that it's supposed to push out of the **top** of the parent, it will break and you will get the same result.

A more dynamic solution would be:

```
.group:hover {
   z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: Using your second solution worked! I had tried to set z-index to 999 on the group element itself, instead of on hover.
There can be some odd behavior if someone mouses over the tooltip to keep it open with the cursor outside the group, but it's a minor issue that I can live with.
(I didn't go with the first option because I have some code that makes the tooltip appear above the item if the item is at the bottom of the screen)